# pushing values in to drop down after Navigation in BB 10 cascades

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10

I have a Tabbed pane in bb 10  cascades and one of my Tab is like...in this link

http://pastebin.com/LRzyNdHZ (paste this link  in address bar, if it doesn't open)

and As you observe ,in "Add/Delete Symbols" Action Item, I try  to "AddOrDelete.qml" where I have a Drop down. you can find that  "AddOrDelete.qml" in this link

http://pastebin.com/mw1nE7yj

now i have a method in "DatabaseOperations.cpp" like...

```
QList<QString>   DatabaseOperations::readRecords(QString tableName){

QList<QString> sym_ID_List;
  // 1. Get the local DB connection. Note, called database()
  //    Will automatically open a connection to the database
     QSqlDatabase database = QSqlDatabase::database(); // opens the default database.

  // 2. Create a query to search for the records
     QSqlQuery query(database);
     const QString sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+tableName;

     if (query.exec(sqlQuery)) {

         // Get the field indexes. We know the order of the fields, and could skip this step.
         // However this will still work if the fi changeldse order in the query string.
         const int customerIDField = query.record().indexOf("SymbolId");

         // 3. Start navigating through the records by calling the 'next' function.
        //     When there are no longer any records it will return false.
         int recordsRead = 0;
         while (query.next()) {
             // 4. Access the data (stored in the query) via the field indexes
             //    and add the data to the model.
            if(!query.value(1).toString().contains("skipRecord")){
                //alert("recordsRead"+query.value(1).toString());
                sym_ID_List.insert(recordsRead,query.value(1).toString());
            }

             recordsRead++;
         }
         qDebug() << "Read " << recordsRead << " records succeeded";
         if (recordsRead == 0) {
            // alert(tr("The customer table is empty."));
         }
     } else {
        // alert(tr("Read records failed: %1").arg(query.lastError().text()));
     }

     // 6. Optionally close the database connection if we no longer plan to use it
     database.close();
     return sym_ID_List;
```

}

now i would like to push these values in to drop down which is defined in "AddOrDelete.qml.

currently I am in Home Screen(i.e Tabbed pane with four Tabs... one of the tab is given in First link).I navigate to "AddOrDelete.qml" file From Action Item with Id : "Add/Delete Symbols".I have only one app.cpp file where I have Lode HomeScreen, like this...

```
ApplicationUI::ApplicationUI(bb::cascades::Application *app) : QObject(app){

qmlRegisterType < Timer > ("CustomTimer", 1, 0, "Timer");
QmlDocument *qml = QmlDocument::create("asset:///Template.qml").parent(this);
qml->setContextProperty("_app", this);
TabbedPane *root = qml->createRootObject<TabbedPane>();
app->setScene(root);
```

}

For your Information, I did the navigation from Qml Itself. To push the Vaues from the DatabaseOpartion(), Do i need to Create a seperate .CPP for "AddOrDelete.qml". If so How Can i link "App.cpp" file and "second.cpp" file. how can i navigate to and from Home screen(Tabbed pane). I have been faceing this problem since last week, I think i get a solution here,

Thanks!!!

Comment: If I understand correctly (and I read whole thing 4x), what you want is to put data from _readRecords()_, which is _QList<QString> sym_ID_List_ into DropDown defined in AddOrDelete.qml?

Comment: yes, that Drop down is in another Qml(AddOrDelete.qml) to which i need to navigate from current Tabbed pane Qml.and push those values...

Comment: You want to select from database every second?

Comment: No , when I am Moving   to On/Before AddOrDelete.qml Screening